# Why is the function $H(I, \varphi) = -\epsilon \varphi$ not globally defined on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^{1}$ ?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, dynamical-systems, hamilton-equations

I am reading a research paper concerning Hamiltonian dynamics. It is remarked that the Hamiltonian  " $H(I, \varphi) = -\epsilon \varphi$ is not globally defined on $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^{1}$ ." Here it is meant that $I \in \mathbb{R}$, $\varphi \in \mathbb{S}^{1}$ and $\epsilon$ is a small positive parameter (but that's not important, just treat it as some constant).

I don't understand why the function $H$ is not globally defined. This implies it should be multivalued on the cylinder, but how does the periodicity in $\varphi$ give rise to the multiple possible values of $H$?

Answer (score 0):

You should have, for example, $H(I,0)=H(I,2\pi)$, but this doesn't happen.

Comment: But we defined $ \varphi  \in  \mathbb{S}^{1}$ so surely then $H(I,0) = H(I, 2\pi) =0$ ? @Jonas

Comment: No, $H(I,2\pi)=-\epsilon 2\pi\ne0$. For example, $-\epsilon \cos\varphi$ would be defined globally.

Comment: I don't understand this, since we have $\varphi \mbox{mod} 2\pi$ thus $\varphi =  0 \equiv 2\pi$, right? @Jonas

Comment: But $H$ takes values in $\mathbb R$, not in $\mathbb S^1$, if it is an Hamiltonian. So, you can't take$\bmod2\pi$.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks - yes, in Hamiltonian context, indeed that's the case and we have $H: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. It just wasn't 100% clear to me @Jonas