# What is the difference between $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto \mathbb{S}^{1}$ and $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Does defining in what space the domain of a function lies in apriori determine in what space the range of that function will be?

Let's have an example. Suppose I take $f(x) = x$. I assume that $x \in \mathbb{S}^{1}$. Does this mean automatically that $f(x) \in \mathbb{S}^{1}$, i.e. $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto  \mathbb{S}^{1}$ and so $f(x)$ is well-defined?

Or we have no way of determining the domain of $f$ yet and thus we still may assign  $f(x) \in \mathbb{R}$, hence putting $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$?  In which case the function is not well-defined (in fact, it will be discontinuous)...

Thanks!

Comment: A function always has a specified domain and range. Always always always. Doesn't make sense otherwise.

Comment: @AJY Or at least a specified codomain. The range is, in my opinion, a derived property (the subset of the codomain consisting of the elements that are actually hit by $f$).

Comment: Thanks. So, in case of $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ we can "pretend" we have $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and assign those values to $f$, right? E.g. $f(1)=1$, $f(2.5 \mbox{mod}1) = 2.5$, etc... @AJY

Comment: @Alex Well you can of course map elements from $\mathbb{S}^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$, but it won't be the identity.

Comment: @Arthur Fair enough.

Comment: We can still write $f(x) = x$, though, right? @AJY

Comment: I think maybe what you mean to ask is, "Do certain 'descriptions' of functions only apply to certain domains and codomains?" The answer here is yes. For instance, it wouldn't make sense to define $g(x) = 2x$ if your domain was an urn of colored balls. Certain ways of *defining* a function only make sense if we assume the domain and/or codomain have certain structures. The case of $f(x) = x$ is a simple example because this only requires that the domain and codomain be sets with a certain relation, namely the former is a subset of the latter.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you can write it. But if you handed it to another person, they would have no clue what you're talking about, and be rightly confused. Writing $f(x) = x$ makes sense if and only if the domain is contained in the codomain. Writing $f: \mathbb{S}^1 \to \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x$ is nonsense.

Comment: I would say that $f(x)=x$ makes sense for a function $f:A\to B$ if $A$ is a subset of $B$, but not otherwise.

Comment: I would also say it makes sense if $B$ is a quotient of $A$ and it's the case that $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $x\sim y$.

Comment: Yes I agree that $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ doesn't make sense. How would you write it instead? @AJY

Comment: Another point that may be confusing you has to do with quotient sets. If $B$ is a quotient set of $A$ w.r.t. an equivalence relation $\sim$, then we have a function $f:A\to B$ defined by $f(x)=[x]$ (which can be written $f(x)=x$ as Dan Rust points out, if you know what you are doing). But, observe that you absolutely cannot have a function $f:B\to A$ in this case. So $f(2.5\bmod1)=2.5$ is **wrong**. We have $(2.5\bmod1)=(1.5\bmod1)$, so unless $2.5=1.5$ in your space the function will not be well defined.

Comment: You can define $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{S}^1, f(x)=x$ when you think of $\Bbb{S}^1$ as $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$. That has only one plausible interpretation (and is well-defined) even though it often comes together with the apologetic phrase *standard abuse of notation*.

Comment: "not well defined function" - yes, that's exactly what I $\textbf{stated}$ in my initial question! (But for my purpose I actually want to allow for such "functions".) With this in mind, is the statement $f: \mathbb{S}^{1} \mapsto  \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ ok ?@JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Just to clarify. My interest in this comes from this other recent question I posted: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2077603/why-is-the-function-hi-varphi-epsilon-varphi-not-globally-defined-on @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: Anyway, you can try to do the following: $f:\Bbb{S}^1\to\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$.

Comment: If you want to be slightly more rigorous, you could even say $f([x])=x$ for all $x\in[0,1)$ where $[x]$ is the equivalence class of $x$ modulo $1$.

Comment: @Alex I have no idea what you're trying to write. No idea whatsoever. So therefore, I have no idea how you ought to write it.

Comment: Yes this looks better @DanRust

Comment: Agreed. Dan Rust's way is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Implicit in the definition of a function is a domain and codomain. That is, two functions $f:A\to B$ and $g:C\to D$ are equal if and only if $A=C$, $B=D$, and $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in A$.

So in the case you're considering, we have a function $f:\Bbb{S}^1\to B$ for some set $B$, and $f(x)=x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{S}^1$. Since by definition of a function we must have $x=f(x)\in B$ for all $B$, you can at least say that $\Bbb{S}^1\subseteq B$, but that's about it. For instance, $B$ could be $\Bbb{S}^1$ itself, or $B$ could be $\Bbb{R}^2$.

I'm not quite sure what you mean by assigning a value $f(x)=x\in\Bbb{R}$. There is certainly no canonical way to assign to each $x$ a value in $\Bbb{R}$. Maybe if you can explain that better I can update my answer to address it.

Answer (score 0):

Formally,  a function $f : A\rightarrow B$, is a subset of the cartesian product $A\times B$ (with certain constraints). In that sense, the symbol "$f$" already encodes in it both of the sets $A$ and $B$. I would also note that the codomain $B$ alone can have an have actual implications on question regrding the function; for example, a function $f : A\rightarrow B_1$ can be [open](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps), while another function $g : A\rightarrow B_2$ is not open, even if $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in A$.